# Getting only certain files from Zend SVN

Tags: svn, zend-framework

I use a portion of ZEND framework and want to be able to update only those files, those files are few directories and few files from library/Zend directory.

I know I can copy only those direcotries and update them, but how can I do it with files in that library/Zend directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a library/Zend directory, and set up [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) Subversion property for it. For example:

```
svn propedit svn:externals ./library/Zend
```

Set it to something like this:

```
Acl http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Acl
Config http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Config
```

Then, running `svn update` in your project root will only update Acl and Config to the latest version taken from ZF Subversion trunk.

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals